# Removing Duplicates from a Linked List?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Hello I was doing an algorithm problem where you remove duplicates from a SORTED linked List

and this is what I have :

```
function removeDuplicatesFromLinkedList(linkedList) {
    let currentNode = linkedList;
    console.log('currentNode', currentNode)
    while (currentNode) {
        let nextDifferentNode = currentNode.next;
        console.log('assignment', nextDifferentNode)
        while (nextDifferentNode && nextDifferentNode.value === currentNode.value) {
            nextDifferentNode = nextDifferentNode.next
                    console.log('nextDifferentNode', nextDifferentNode)
        }
        currentNode.next = nextDifferentNode
        currentNode = nextDifferentNode
    }
  return linkedList
```

}

the argument parameter linkedList refers to the head node and its next value. I was wondering why we are returning linkedList at the end, does this mean we mutated the .next properties of the original linkedList nodes?

Comment: yes, by changing some of the next values we remove the duplicates.

Comment: so are we mutating the original argument parameter? because its returning linkedList at the end of the function

Comment: look at my answer if this removes the confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A LinkedList is like `node1 -> node2 -> node3 -> ..... null`. The input parameter, `linkedList` is the head of the linked list. The `node1` in my example. While we mutate the list we want to return the head at the end, which unfortunately is named `linkedList` here.

To clear that we are going to change the name of the input parameter to the function. We name it `head` because its really just the head of the linked list while the linked list is the whole data structure. As we move forward we mutate the next pointers as needed to drop duplicate nodes.

```js
function removeDuplicatesFromLinkedList(head) {
    let currentNode = head;
    console.log('currentNode', currentNode)
    while (currentNode) {
        let nextDifferentNode = currentNode.next;
        console.log('assignment', nextDifferentNode)
        while (nextDifferentNode && nextDifferentNode.value === currentNode.value) {
            nextDifferentNode = nextDifferentNode.next
                    console.log('nextDifferentNode', nextDifferentNode)
        }
        currentNode.next = nextDifferentNode
        currentNode = nextDifferentNode
    }
  return head
```

As you can see we receive the `head`, assign it to a variable that we are change on work on and keep `head` to return at the end.